# Choosing an Appropriate ADC Clock Source

Tags: adc, clock

I'm currently in the process of changing the clock source for our scanning ADC (ADS1158) from an internal oscillator with external crystal to an external clock.The datasheet doesn't really give much guidance on clock selection (not nearly the detail that went into requirements for the internal oscillator/crystal implementation), just that the clock frequency can be up to 16MHz and a 50 ohm resistor be placed in series.

When I search for clocks I'm inundated with the number of options there are and I'm not really sure what is needed, what is overkill, what is not appropriate. At the very basic level, I'd like to know if I should use a clock generator or a clock oscillator. If it's a clock oscillator, do I need load caps? If it's a clock generator, are there any other considerations I should implement?

Thanks in advance-

Comment: Read the data sheet carefully. That 50 ohm resistor, if used, it CAN help, should be placed close to the source of the external clock, not at the CLKIO input pin. But it's not required at all if the clock source is well behaved with no under/over shoot.

Comment: What are your sampling requirements?  What are you trying to sample (DC, AC)?  And if AC what frequency?  If you're trying to obtain phase history from your input, even a moderate amount of jitter can be a deal breaker.

Answer (score 0):

There is a section in the datasheet on using the chip with a clock oscillator. They mention "clean of jitter" and allowing for a series resistor (suggested 50Ω near the source- which is the oscillator).

Since it's a relatively low resolution (16-bit) converter, just about any commercial clock oscillator based on a quartz crystal should be good enough not to compromise the ADC specifications. You don't need load caps, but the oscillator datasheet should give some guidance as to supply bypassing, if not, a ceramic capacitor of 100nF or more near the oscillator supply pins and keep the clock line relatively short.

A minor detail, unless you get it wrong, make sure the oscillator supply voltage is compatible (whatever your DVdd is) and that it outputs a CMOS level digital square wave (not a sine wave).

A clock generator chip would allow a master clock oscillator to supply one or more (in general, different) output frequencies that are locked to the master, and can itself reduce jitter due to internal PLL filtering. I doubt it's necessary or desirable unless you have a bunch of different clocks you're trying to replace and are willing to deal with the learning curve for another programmable (and proprietary) chip.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what you are using the ADC for and what is the input signal frequency. The datasheet of ADS1158 is very ambiguous when it says that the clock should be "clean of jitter" because jitter cannot be 0.

If only the SNR matters, refer to the following app note for more details
[https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/maximum-snr-vs-clock-jitter.html#:~:text=The%20amount%20of%20clock%20jitter,maximum%20performance%20of%20the%20ADC](https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/maximum-snr-vs-clock-jitter.html#:%7E:text=The%20amount%20of%20clock%20jitter,maximum%20performance%20of%20the%20ADC).

You can keep the SNR generated by clock jitter a decade lower than the other noise sources in the ADC so that it does not affect the overall SNR of the system.